# Javascript not working on Safari, works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

I'm doing a simple calculation within a loop.  This piece of code works on Chrome, but not safari.  I checked the browser compatibility for all of the methods, but I'm not seeing any issues.  Hope someone can help.  Thanks!

```
//loop through all of the SKUs in the table
for (let i = 0; i < totalTableProducts.length; i++) {
  skuCaseValue[i] = sku[i].innerText.slice(-2);  //get the last 2 digits of the SKU
  skuCaseValue[i] = parseInt(skuCaseValue[i]);  //convert to num

  //on input of quantity, change the total to the quantity * last 2 digits of SKU
  quantityInput[i].oninput = function(){  
    quantityValue[i] = quantityInput[i].value;  
    if (quantityValue[i] == ""){
      totalQuantity[i].innerText = "";
    } else{
      quantityValue[i] = parseInt(quantityValue[i]);
      quantityValue[i] *= skuCaseValue[i];
      quantityValue[i] = quantityValue[i].toString();
      totalQuantity[i].innerText = quantityValue[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post error from the developer tool's Console

Comment: You need to elaborate on "not working", you gave us code and said it works on one platform but you dont explain how it does not work on the other, what happens when it runs? What is the intended output? Are there any errors?

Comment: There is high probability that is due to `oninput` funciton that is not fired and becasue safari doesn't support neither mozilla firefox instead you have to use `onchange` even to fire event when element loses it's focus  and it can applied to element like : <input>, <select>, and <textarea> or if you want to fire on each key press use `onkeydown` event handler to handle key press events and update DOM

Comment: Thanks.  There isn't an error showing in the console.  It's just calculating 0 no matter what is entered into the input.  I'll try out onchange and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: It seems to have more to do with the array, which ends up being [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...]

Comment: skuCaseValue[i] = sku[i].innerText.slice(-2);
This line is logging 0 on each run through the loop.